How to use "generic color" to describe tertiary colors in gradient logo if filing for color claimed trademark?
With a multicolored gradient logo (not just a two-color gradient) and filing a color logo trademark in the EU, there is a need to describe the colors using "generic" color names.
In such a case, should you describe only the gradient end stops or the whole color range?
Also, how do you actually describe any tertiary colors using "generic" color names? Is there an official list of such color names, or do you just write for example, "lime" or "yellow-green" if that color isn't clearly a primary or secondary color with a common "generic" name?
Or would specifying the RGB values work?

Discussion and examples under a possibly now superseded rule. https://guidelines.euipo.europa.eu/1803468/1786113/trade-mark-guidelines/9-6-----------9-3-6-colour-marks
